# Force "www" only in cases other than subdomain (nginx)

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, redirect

I have a problem with Nginx (Ubuntu 18), I need to force the "www." in dynamic domains, it is neither multiple domain, it is really dynamic, it can be any one that point to the server.

Currently, I'm forcing www for everything, but if the user uses a subdomain, the server is forcing "www.yourdomain.com", and I wanted it in CASE to be a subdomain, not force the www.

**Current redirect code:**

```
if ($host! ~^ www\.) {
    rewrite ^ $scheme://www.$host$uri permanent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

hiho, 
maybe this can help you, if i undertood..

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8199231/how-to-setup-mass-dynamic-virtual-hosts-in-nginx

and at you case must be this way the nginx code

```
if ($host! ~^ www\.) {
rewrite ^ $scheme://www.$host$request_uri;
}
```

using $request_uri, the rewrite will keep the url after the / for any situation...

if you use permanent, some cases it can rewrite to main domain.

Comment: Thanks, but is the same... I need something like that: if( !$subdomain && $host! ~^ www\.)